# Google Maps Engine API Client Library for Python to create a table asset

Tags: python, google-maps, google-app-engine, python-2.7

I'm trying to use Google Maps Engine API Client Library for Python to create table object using the following code:

```
service = build('mapsengine', 'v1', developerKey=api_key, http=http)
table = service.tables()
request = table.create(body = body)
response = request.execute()
```

Where `body` is the following:

```
{
  "projectId": "deletedProjectID",
  "name": "turf zones of Uppsala ",
  "description": "Table to contain zones to plot",
  "tags": [
    "turf", "turfing", "uppsala"
  ],
  "schema": {
    "columns": [
      {
        "name": "dateCreated",
        "type": "points"
      },
      {
        "name": "latitude",
        "type": "points"
      },
      {
        "name": "longitude",
        "type": "points"
      },
      {
        "name": "name",
        "type": "points"
      }

    ]
  }
}
```

However, I get the error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
HttpError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-76-698f94a34d91> in <module>()
----> 1 response = request.execute()

C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy32\User\lib\site-packages\oauth2client\util.pyc in positional_wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    130         else: # IGNORE
    131           pass
--> 132       return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
    133     return positional_wrapper
    134 

C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy32\User\lib\site-packages\apiclient\http.pyc in execute(self, http, num_retries)
    721       callback(resp)
    722     if resp.status >= 300:
--> 723       raise HttpError(resp, content, uri=self.uri)
    724     return self.postproc(resp, content)
    725 

HttpError: <HttpError 400 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/mapsengine/v1/tables?alt=json&key=[deleted] returned "A value is required.">
```

I've tried using `body = json.dumps(body)` but I still get the same error. The only argument which `.create()` takes in a body ([docs](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/mapsengine/v1/python/latest/mapsengine_v1.tables.html#create)) and I based the content of the body from this [Google Maps Engine tutorial](https://developers.google.com/maps-engine/documentation/tutorial-create-map#step_1_create_an_empty_table_in_google_maps_engine). On the Google Developers Console I can see that I've making requests to my project (although they've all resulted in errors). Could somebody explain what I've done wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem, in fact this is how I came across your question. Yes, the `body` looks  fine, but only at the first sight:

```
body = {
    "projectId" : "xxx",
    "name": "API test 2",
    "layerType": "image"
}

config = json.dumps(body)
print type(config)
```

Spoiler: it is a string!

Solution:

1. `body = json.loads(body)`, which will create a dictionary for you or
2. Pass `body` directly to the `create` method, making sure that it is a proper dictionary

One more thing: it also seems that you are missing a mandatory parameter: `layerType`. Check  the documentation [for create method](https://developers.google.com/maps-engine/documentation/reference/v1/layers/create%20for%20create%20method%22). I guess it will be `vector` in your case.